# Exception Value: name 'start_date' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error during my admin testing on save of a habit in my Habit app. I don't know what to add to this code that would satisfy a definition of 'start_date'. Will you please show me where I've gone wrong.

Exception Value: name 'start_date' is not defined
Exception Location: //models.py in duration, line 20
which is, a = datetime.strptime(str(start_date), date_format)

```
class Habit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    goal_nbr = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    goal_description = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="habit", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def duration(self):
        date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
        a = datetime.strptime(str(start_date), date_format)
        b = datetime.strptime(str(end_date), date_format)
        delta = b - a
        return f'{ delta } days'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Goal Name: {self.name} Goal Target: {self.goal_nbr} Description: {self.goal_description} Duration: {self.duration} days Beginning: {self.start_date} Ending: {self.end_date}"
```

Comment: use self.start_date

Answer (score 3):

These are attributes of the `self` object, not names that you can access:

```
    @property
    def duration(self):
        date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
        a = datetime.strptime(str(self.start_date), date_format)
        b = datetime.strptime(str(self.end_date), date_format)
        delta = b - a
        return f'{ delta } days'
```

That being said, since `start_date` and `end_date` are `DateField`s, `self.start_date` is a `date` object. So you can calculate this as:

```
    @property
    def duration(self):
        delta = self.end_date - self.start_date
        return f'{delta.days} days'
```